# Two DMLs based on Same Subquery

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I need to cancel some orders, and then insert a row into another table, both based on the same subquery.

There is a very small chance that the subquery  will return different rows between the time that the 1st and 2nd DMLs are issued.

But is there a proper way to do this such the orders updated are the same orders that are inserted into the cancellations table?

I am using Oracle and JDBC.  Thanks.

```
update orders
set status = 'cancel'
where order_number in (select order_number from some_other_table_where...)


insert into order_cancellations
 select order_number select order_number from some_other_table_where...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are five approaches that spring to mind:

(1) Put a trigger on the `orders` table so whenever the `status` is set to `'cancel'`, a row is inserted into `order_cancellations`.

(2) Use the returning clause in `insert`.  Do the insert first and use this information for the update.

(3) Add a creation date to `order_cancellations` and do this insert first.  Then update `orders` using the just-inserted rows

(4) Wrap the two statements in a transaction (this might require locking the other tables).

(5) Load the subquery data into a temporary table and use that table for both operations.

I also wonder if you could eliminate the need for the cancellations table just by having a `cancellation_date` column in the `orders` table.